# JPA 2.0 - using @OrdercColumn with an unidirectional @ManyToMany relationship with Hibernate 4.0.1

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, jpa-2.0

Problem
I have two entities (Column and Table). A Column has a List for storing joinpath to this column and so I need very important the order of the tables.

Here are the entity definitions.

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="Column_")
public class Column extends PersistenceEntity<Column> implements Serializable, Comparable<Column> {

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "column_joinpath",
joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "column_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@OrderColumn(name="order_index")
private List<Table> joinPath;

/**
* Default constructor
*/
public Column() {
}
```

The Table-entity has no reference to column, because the table shouldn't know in which joinPath it is used.

Create SQL-Statement

for Table

```
create table Table_ (
    id varchar(36) not null,
    displayName varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

for Column

```
create table Column_ (
    id varchar(36) not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

for JoinTable

```
create table column_joinpath (
 column_id varchar(36) not null, -- with FK
 table_id varchar(36) not null, -- with FK
 order_index integer not null,  
 primary key (column_id, table_id, order_index)
)
```

PROBLEM: Hibernate will ignore the @OrderColumn at follow JPQL

Select t.displayName from Column c join c.joinPath t where c = :col

Hibernate will produce the following SQL without an order by statements

```
    /* Select
    t.displayName 
from
    Column c 
join
    c.joinPath t 
where
    c = :col */ select
        table2_.displayName as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Column_ column0_ 
    inner join
        column_joinpath joinpath1_ 
            on column0_.id=joinpath1_.column_id 
    inner join
        Table_ table2_ 
            on joinpath1_.table_id=table2_.id 
    where
        column0_.id=?
```

as workaround I use a native sql query

```
Select t.displayName from Column_ c inner join column_joinpath joinpath on c.id=joinpath.column_id inner join Table_ t on joinpath.table_id=t.id where c.id=:col order by joinpath.order_index
```

Is there anybody how can translate from SQL to JPQL or have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Norman

Answer (score 0):

hibernate uses the order_index client side to populate the List but does not specify an order by. you could load the Column entity eager fetching the JoinPath and get the displayname from the JoinPath collection.

```
jpql: "from Column c Join fetch c.JoinPath"

for (Table t : column.getJoinPath())
{
    // do something with t.getDisplayName();
}
```